# Why am i getting groupingBy method error?

Tags: java, java-stream

So im reading OCP book there is a code that looks like this, and I'm typing all of this not needed info cause the stackoverflow says my post is mostly a code. and here i thought this a stackoverflow.
So the question
When I'm typing this code

```
Stream<String> ohMy = Stream.of("lions", "tigers", "bears");
Map<Integer, Optional<Character>> map = ohMy.collect(
    groupingBy(
        String::length,
        mapping(s -> s.charAt(0),
            minBy(Comparator.naturalOrder()))));
System.out.println(map); // {5=Optional[b], 6=Optional[t]}
```

I'm getting an error

```
Error:(25, 27) java: no suitable method found for groupingBy(String::length,java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.Object,capture#1 of ?,java.util.Optional<T>>)
    method java.util.stream.Collectors.<T,K>groupingBy(java.util.function.Function<? super T,? extends K>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T,K
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method java.util.stream.Collectors.<T,K,A,D>groupingBy(java.util.function.Function<? super T,? extends K>,java.util.stream.Collector<? super T,A,D>) is not applicable
      (inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
        inferred: java.lang.Object
        upper bound(s): T,java.lang.Comparable<? super T>,java.lang.Object)
    method java.util.stream.Collectors.<T,K,D,A,M>groupingBy(java.util.function.Function<? super T,? extends K>,java.util.function.Supplier<M>,java.util.stream.Collector<? super T,A,D>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T,K,D,A,M
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
```

Cannot figure it out

Comment: @HarshalParekh The problem is that code presented above is not compiling

Comment: I didn't mean the problem in the code. I can see that. I mean what is the bigger problem, what are we trying to solve here? @mslowiak It is possible that there are more than one solutions and for that we need to know the problem.

Comment: it is not compiling and there is no obvious reason that is the problem

Comment: @HarshalParekh    // {5=Optional[b], 6=Optional[t]} the out in the code already

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's a problem connected to `Intellij` distribution.

See link to issue tracker:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-212740

To make it work from Intellij you need to specify `Comparator` type witness:

```
Stream<String> ohMy = Stream.of("lions", "tigers", "bears");
Map<Integer, Optional<Character>> map = ohMy
        .collect(
                groupingBy(
                        String::length, 
                        mapping(s -> s.charAt(0), minBy(Comparator.<Character>naturalOrder()))
                )
        );
System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not working in console either  java8 distribution cant be wrong

Comment: I double-checked with openjdk-8u242-b08 and it compiles well.
Works also on openjdk 11.0.6

Comment: u checked it with type witness or without ?

Comment: with type witness :)

Comment: @DanielBaker this solution definitely works. Alternatively, you can use `groupingBy(String::length, mapping((String s) -> s.charAt(0), minBy(Comparator.naturalOrder())))`. But, perhaps, you actually want something like, `Map<Integer, Character> map = Stream.of("lions", "tigers", "bears").collect( toMap(String::length, (String s) -> s.charAt(0), BinaryOperator.minBy(Comparator.naturalOrder())));` or, even simpler, `Map<Integer, Character> map = Stream.of("lions", "tigers", "bears").collect( toMap(String::length, s -> s.charAt(0), (a,b) -> a>b? b: a));`…

Comment: Just to make this clear, this is not (necessarily) an Intellij bug. The bug report says that Intellij suggests that the type witness is obsolete, whereas then compiling without type witness fails (using javac behind the scenes). So Intellij and javac disagree whether a type witness is necessary. Note that Eclipse compiles the code without the type witness. I think, this time, the bug is on the javac side.